# prevent to open another activity android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activity which are : main activity and login activity.
when login is successfull in login activity then intent will open main activity.
The problem is everytime i press back button the login activity is opened again. i want to minimize app instead of opening login activity again.
i use shared preferences to flag my app if it is loging in. i put boolean value true if the user is logged in.
I used shared preference. and use cekLogin() like this :

```
private boolean cekLogin() {
        boolean login;
        login = config.getBoolean("login", false);
        return login;
    }
```

config is my sharedpreferences.

```
if(cekLogin){
//do not open login activity again when back button pressed <--- i don't know how to do this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your login.java file

```
//Assuming this is the part where you open the second activity:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.java);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

When you click the back button on the second activity, the application will go back to the home page since you finished the login activity.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml add this inside the LoginActivity tag:
*android:noHistory="true"*
This will switch off the history for this activity so that when you press back button, this activity will be always skipped. Since you get to the MainActivity only if Login is successful I think this is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can override [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) so that when the user pressed back the app closes, instead of returning to the previous activity.

Or you could finish() the previous activity after starting an activity on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is everytime i press back button the login activity is opened again.
```

for this you got two options: either you finish the login activity and then go to main activity, or you may override the method `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

When login is succesfull store the value in sharedpref before that you have to first check whether their is login already in sharedpref if yes then it will directly open the main activity otherwise it open the login screen.

```
 if(isLogin)
          {
                  startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
             }
              else
              {
                  startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

              }
```

where isLogin is a boolean variable declared false first and change the value to true in sharedpref  if it has been loginsuccessfull